# Transposing a Key Value pair SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which consists of a few columns, including a Key Value pairing. So imagine:

```
BookID, Key, Value
MyBook, Price, 19.99
MyBook, ISBN, 987878495793
MyBook, Pages, 354
MyBook2, ...., ....
MyBook2, ...., ....
```

I need to get this into the format:

```
BookID, Price, ISBN, Pages
MyBook, 19.99, 987878495793, 354
MyBook2,.....,.............,....
```

i.e transposing the cells- how would I do this in SQL?

Comment: Are your final columns fixed? Or could new keys appear in the data that you then need to appear as new columns in your results? *(If it's fixed, look at PIVOT and UNPIVOT, if it's dynamic you'll need to write Dynamic SQL to adapt the PIVOT to encorporate the new keys.)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT
  BookID, Price, ISBN, Pages
FROM
(
  SELECT BookID, Key, Value FROM yourTable
)
  AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Value) FOR Key IN (Price, ISBN, Pages)
)
  AS PivotTable
ORDER BY
  BookID
```

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(SQL.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28SQL.105%29.aspx)

Comment: How would this work if _value_ were not a numeric value but a textfield?

Comment: @Calyx - In place of `SUM()`, you can use `MAX()` as a valid aggregate for strings, or in newer versions `STRING_AGG()`, depending on intent.