# How to store and retrieve multiple tables data into key value pair?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-attribute-value, keyvaluepair

I am working on a requirement where product needs a flexibility to add Lists of multiple number of columns. I am trying to fit  data in data model with the help of key value pair.

For example -

I have a list Allergy which will have 3 columns Allergy, Reaction and Type
Another list named Lens have only two columns Vendor Name, Cost

My model consists of following table

1. LIST

It consist of LIST_ID and LIST_NAME

2. LIST_ROW_MAP

It consists of LIST_ROW_ID, LIST_ID ( Foreign Key to LIST table) , ORDER ( to save row order)

3  LIST_ITEMS

It consists of LIST_ITEM_ID, LIST_ROW_ID (Foreign key to LIST_ROW_MAP table ) , KEY , VALUE

(Sorry could not post picture as I do not have privilege yet)

Though I can save the data, for retrieving I am facing challenges. 
I tried query marked as answer in below link but it can help when name of columns are known and when it is for single table stored as key value.

[Transposing a Key Value pair SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224954/transposing-a-key-value-pair-sql-table)

I am trying to store multiple table's data so there should be something dynamic.
Please help :)

Comment: Does the key/value pair content need to be filterable? Do you need to be able to write SQL queries against the content to find specific records?

Comment: Yes. I have to show List and their particular LIST_ITEMS on front end

Comment: Does it only need to be filterable in code or also via SQL? Sorry for the continued clarification questions.

Comment: Actually we do everything through stored procedure. So via SQL is the correct answer for this question

Comment: Brilliant. I realize the post is tagged as SQL. Just wanted to make sure.